# Difference between Was and Were. Correct usage

Tags: grammar

Which is the correct usage in this case?

> The salary on both days was 500.
>
> The salary on both days were 500.

Answer (score 3):

Since "salary" is singular, "was" must be taken.

This is more apparent in the following sentence:

> The salary was 500 on both days.

Alternatively you could write

> The salaries on both days were 500.

if you would like to point out there are multiple salaries.